# PHP, doing mysql update based on loop iteration

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file that works up to a certain point but I need a bit of help on the loop for doing a MySQl Insert.

The following preforms a SELECT and then stores the Order ID for all records that have a order_status of 'S'. This works perfectly, printing each appropriate order ID.

I then push those affected ORder IDs to an array so that I can keep them stored for various functions.

```
    //Query for checking all records in order_status
    $orderCheck = "
            SELECT 
                order_id,
                order_status
            FROM order_status
    ";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqlConn, $orderCheck);
    $order_ids = array();


    //loop results to gather order IDs and store them
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        $order_id = $row['order_id'];
        if ($row['order_status'] == "S")
            {
            array_push($order_ids, $order_id);
            }
        }

    //print_r($order_ids);
    //This does indeed print the correct order Ids
```

The following portion needs some work and I'm not quite sure what to do here. I'm iterating and foreach of those iterations I have an update, but i fear the syntax is incorrect on the update and I don't know if I'd need to do another array in here.

```
    //This is where I'm stuck//
    //Now I need to iterate through those orderIDs and update is_placement to 1, since it's a bit column, and udpate date_updated to curdate()

    for($i=0; $i<count($order_id); $i++) {

        $sql = "UPDATE order_status SET is_placement = '1' and date_updated = curdate() WHERE order_id = '$order_id'"; //I don't believe this syntax is correct    
    }
```

Basically, I need to preform a mysql update for each iteration of the previously stored $order_id array.

Any ideas or suggestions/guidance are much appreciated.

UPDATE:

output of the array:

```
[287] => 11605809
[288] => 11605817
[289] => 11605825
[290] => 11605863
[291] => 11605869
[292] => 11605870
[293] => 11605875
[294] => 12605471
[295] => 12605643
[296] => 12605715
[297] => 12605778
[298] => 12605817
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Can you share the output of the array?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I updated with the last few elements of that array

Comment: So the values to the right are indeed the correct order IDs

Comment: `count($order_id)` should be `count($order_ids)`... and then you use `$order_ids[$i]` in the sql. (or what Jay answered with)

Comment: `and` in update query should be `,`.

Comment: Why couldn't you do one single query: `UPDATE order_status SET is_placement = '1', date_updated = curdate() WHERE order_status = 'S'` ? And ... don't name a field the same as a table name, ITS CONFUSING ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat I had originally had it set up to do that, but after changing some other scripts that interact with this, I needed to store the order Ids with status set to 'S' for several processes and this is just the first of those processes

Comment: Ok, good reason to pull them out first. I wasn't aware of the other interaction. All's good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes little sense to ask MySQL for *all* the orders, and then select manually those with status S.

Better:

```
// Select only orders in status S.
$orderCheck = "SELECT order_id FROM order_status WHERE order_status = 'S';"

$result = mysqli_query($mysqlConn, $orderCheck);
$order_ids = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $order_ids[] = $row['order_id'];
}
```

Now you want to update those records. If you do it one by one, you do:

```
foreach ($order_ids as $order_id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE order_status SET is_placement = 1, date_updated = DATE(NOW()) WHERE order_id = '$order_id';";
    // EXECUTE
}
```

A faster way would be (I'm not adding quotes, assuming that order ids are numeric, but if they aren't things get a bit more complicated) to put all order ids together and use the `IN` syntax:

```
$bunchOfOrders = implode(',', $order_ids);

$singleQuery = "UPDATE order_status SET is_placement = 1, date_updated = DATE(NOW()) WHERE order_id IN ({$bunchOfOrders})";
```

But you could have done all this in MySQL too:

```
$orderUpdate = "UPDATE order_status SET is_placement = 1, date_updated = NOW() WHERE order_status = 'S';"

$result = mysqli_query($mysqlConn, $orderUpdate);
```

Since the above does not change the order status from S, you can then also run $orderCheck and retrieve the order-ids involved, if necessary.

To be sure that nothing untoward happens, I would also wrap the whole operation inside a transaction.

## Another twist

What if we have to run a series of different modifications depending on some condition (mutually exclusive, of course)?

We can do this with a map, as long as we use deterministic functions and no modification changes the conditions below (so, you can't change order_status in any of the "recipes", or it would influence those that come after):

```
$todo = array(
    "order_status='S'"    => "is_placement = 1, date_updated = DATE(NOW())",
    "order_status='K'"    => "is_placement = 2, date_updated = DATE(NOW())",
    "order_status='L'"    => "owner='NOBODY'",
    "o_s='X' AND a=12"    => "note='A random condition'",
    // We can also supply a "what to do if none of the above":
    "DEFAULT"             => "note='THIS RECORD DOES NOT MATCH'",
);
$else = array();
foreach ($todo as $when => $then) {
    if ('DEFAULT' !== $when) {
        $else[] = "({$when})";
    } else {
        // "ELSE" means when no other condition is matched.
        // i.e. NOT when1 AND NOT when2 AND NOT when3...
        // which is equivalent to NOT ( when1 OR when2 ... )
        $when = "NOT (" . implode(' OR ', $else) . ")";
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE order_status SET {$then} WHERE {$when};";
    // Execute $sql.
}
```

Comment: Question: The only reason I have the select that way is to have all order Ids in the table and then have an array for all with status 's' to do this update, and then I was going to eventually have another process that does a similar thing with all other status codes, other than S. You're saying it would be better to do this, and then just have another query for all status codes <> 'S' and use another array for those?

Comment: I think I've used every single one of these methods in one reason or another. Its nice you listed many of the possible ways to do an operation such as this.

Comment: @TomN. you can run one query `WHERE order_status='S'` and then another query with `WHERE order_status='K'` (or `!= 'S'`). If this is on a multi-client system, you **definitely** want to shield everything within a transaction and/or lock the table, to avoid one of those orders changing status while you're updating them. You probably do not even need the arrays if all you're doing is changing information in a closed script (you do need the arrays if you want to, say, send one confirmation email to each order's representative, or things like that).

Comment: @LSerni ah thank you, that may be another way I look into going with this. I think if I have separate queries for different ORder IDs that might keep it cleaner

Comment: @TomN. I've added something that might be useful.

Comment: Whoa, thank you! That actually will really come in handy as I start to add more conditions to how we change orders based on status. I appreciate the thoughtful answer!

Answer (score 3):

What you could use is a `foreach()` statement:

```
foreach($order_ids AS $order_id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE order_status SET is_placement = '1', date_updated = curdate() WHERE order_id = $order_id";
    // execute the query here
}
```

While you are using information from data contained in your table you should consider learning about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Hey, who downvoted this! I like `foreach` more than `for`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, so nix the iterator and use foreach instead?

Comment: Yes @TomN, it will be cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, so the only thing I missed is that $order_is should be $order_ids. I made an oversight on that 's'. Other than that, my syntax in using that variable is correct then?

Comment: In your original `for()` loop @TomN.?

Comment: Right, I just used the $order_id not knowing if that was the proper way to use it

Comment: In the `for()` loop you would have to use `$order_id[$i]` because of the iterator.

Comment: Gotcha, I'm going to go with the foreach instead and use the syntax you have there. I think that sounds the most appropriate

Comment: In this case it is just cleaner. In other cases the `for()` with an iterator might be the better option. Also note the changes to the SQL query, removing the `AND` and not surrounding `$order_id` with quotes because it is a number.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the initial query so you don't have to loop through anything more than once.

Try this:

```
    //Query for checking all records in order_status
    $orderCheck = "
        SELECT 
        order_id,
        order_status
        FROM order_status
        WHERE order_status = 'S'
    ";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqlConn, $orderCheck);
$order_ids = array();

//loop results to gather order IDs and store them
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE order_status SET is_placement = '1' and date_updated = curdate() WHERE order_id = '$row[0]'";
}
```